# Clearly documented reading of emails functionality with python win32com outlook

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to understand outlook interaction through win32com better.  I've been unable to find clear documentation that allows me to utilise win32com to read emails effectively, from my current investigation it seems like a fairly regular sentiment by users.  Thus comes the following information and request:

Could someone;

**1. Give a link to the location of clear documentation (if it exists)**

**2. Expand on the below**

Below is the current functionality I've found based on reading other peoples code.

Take the below code:

```
import win32com

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages=inbox.Items

for message in messages:
    attachments = message.attachments

    for attachment in attachments:
        pass
```

The objects used above have the following functionality that I'm aware of:

inbox -

```
.Folders
.Items
```

messages -

```
.GetFirst()
.GetLast()
.GetNext()
.GetPrevious()
.Attachments
```

message -

```
.Subject
.Body
.To
.Recipients
.Sender
.Sender.Address
```

attachments -

```
.item()
.Count
```

attachment -

```
.filename
```

If you know of any more functionality then please add to this in your answers.

Comment: I have three outlook profiles setup on my machine. How do I choose which profile to choose in python?

Comment: Sorry, limited for time. I presume you need to replace GetDefaultFolder with a pointer to another profile. I reckon you will not be too far away exploring the following link and drop-down options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-object-outlook. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I need to point to another profile. I saw the link that you provided but did not get any related information. Please let me know if you find information regarding this.

Comment: `message.SenderEmailAddress`

Comment: how to filter records using subject

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The visual basic for applications reference is your friend here. Try starting with this link...

[Interop Outlook Mailitem Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx)

For instance I can see that message will probably have additional properties than what you listed above. For example.

- message.CC
- message.Importance
- message.LastModificationTime

Comment: This is the exact documentation I was looking for, your help has been very much appreciated.

Comment: In question we are not providing username and password anywhere. So how outlook authenticate the account.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM via local outlook app or nah?

Answer (score 38):

For everyone wondering how to reach any default folder not just "Inbox" here's the list:

```
3  Deleted Items
4  Outbox
5  Sent Items
6  Inbox
9  Calendar
10 Contacts
11 Journal
12 Notes
13 Tasks
14 Drafts
```

There are more (Reminders, Sync errors etc.); you can get whole list with this code (inspired by [John Cook's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801030/6713210) to Folders):

```
import win32com
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
for i in range(50):
    try:
        box = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(i)
        name = box.Name
        print(i, name)
    except:
        pass
```

*I'm not pasting the whole list here, because mine is in Polish and wouldn't be really helpful.*

Comment: To get this to work properly you may need to modify the import statement to read: import win32com.client. Initially this solution didn't work properly on Python 3.6. Tweaking it with the addition of .cleint resolved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I thought I'd add something on navigating through folders too - this is all derived from the Microsoft documentation above, but might be helpful to have here, particularly if you're trying to go anywhere in the Outlook folder structure except the inbox.

You can navigate through the folders collection using `folders` - note in this case, there's no `GetDefaultFolder` after the `GetNamespace` (otherwise you'll likely end up with the inbox).

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace('MAPI')
folder = outlook.Folders[1]
```

The number is the index of the folder you want to access. To find out how many sub-folders are in there:

```
folder.Count
```

If there more sub-folders you can use another `Folders` to go deeper:

```
folder.Folders[2]
```

`Folders` returns a list of sub-folders, so to get the names of all the folders in the current directory, you can use a quick loop.

```
for i in range(folder.Count):
    print (folder[i].Name)
```

Each of the sub-folders has a `.Items` method to get a list of the emails.

Answer (score 3):

For attachments
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment
(see Properities)

```
attachment.FileName
attachment.Type
attachment.Position
attachment.BlockLevel
attachment.Class
attachment.DisplayName
attachment.Parent
attachment.Session
attachment.Size
attachment.Index
attachment.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

This page is definitely the most complete resource for pywin32!

Just one to add on:

```
 message.senton.date() # for received date only 
 message.senton.time() # for received time only
 message.senton # for date and time
```

Also, just found out the case of the message properties like senton, attachment and all other properties shown in 'Interop Outlook Mailitem Properties' shared by Genome above can be write as fully lowercase or fully uppercase or mix.

Answer (score 0):

**How to use Microsoft Documents to Guide `win32com` Code:**

**1. Start with the Namespace Interface:**

Start by importing `win32com` and creating an `outlook` object, which represents the [‘Outlook Namespace Interface’](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespace?view=outlook-pia)(the link has all properties and methods available to call). This object serves as your starting point for accessing everything in the Outlook app:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

**2. Navigate the Documentation:**

Navigation of the documentation is best done by starting at the [‘Outlook Namespace Interface’](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespace?view=outlook-pia) and click on hyperlinks for the method or properties you want to call to see return types.

Alternatively:

You can check the 'Class' property, which returns an integer. Refer to this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia) to determine the associated Interface. Then search for pages labeled '____ Interface,' where ____ represents the object you are interested in.

---

**Example Navigating Email Accounts, Folders, and Emails:**

**level 1 is email accounts**

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folders = outlook.Folders
for i, folder in enumerate(folders):
    print(i, folder.Name)

# 0 aaa@gmail.com
# 1 bbb@gmail.com
# 2 ccc@gmail.com
```

**level 2 is first level of folders**

```
account = folders[1]  # use index to select account; in this case bbb@gmail.com
account_folders = account.Folders
for i, folder in enumerate(account_folders):
    print(i, folder.Name)

# 0 Deleted Items
# 1 Inbox
# 2 Outbox
# 3 Sent Items
# 4 Notes
# 5 Journal
# … continues on
```

If you have folders inside folders you can continue this pattern.

**Accessing emails:**

```
inbox_folder = account_folders[1]  # select inbox
print("number of email", inbox_folder.Items.Count)   # number of email 231  
for i, email in enumerate(inbox_folder.Items):
    print(i, email.Subject)

# 0 Meeting Time
# 1 Meeting follow-up
# 2 Scheduling another meeting
# 3 Can't make it to today's meeting
# … continues on
```

**Accessing emails properties:**

```
email = inbox_folder.Items[3]
print(email.SenderName)  # Jane Smith
print(email.SentOn)  # 2023-08-31 18:05:23+00:00
print(email.Body)  # Hi John, I can't make today's meeting because ...
```

Complete list of property for an [email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia).