# Python & Outlook COM : Error on getting elements

Tags: python, email, outlook, com

So, I'm trying to implement a simple Python Outlook client retriever for use it later in a Node.JS API. This is my actual code :

```
import win32com.client
import requests

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders[0]
i = folder.Count()
print(i)
```

But I get this error :

```
File ".\MAPI_script\outlook2013_retrieveInbox.py", line 6, in <module>
i = folder.Count()
File "C:\Users\zehav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.Count
```

This error comes up every time I try to get an Outlook folder. I also trying code on this previous post :  [Reading e-mails from Outlook with Python through MAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077625/reading-e-mails-from-outlook-with-python-through-mapi)

And this one too : 
[Clearly documented reading of emails functionality with python win32com outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813814/clearly-documented-reading-of-emails-functionality-with-python-win32com-outlook)

In all those cases, I got a similar error where the COM object seems don't reach anything in Outlook.

If someone have an idea of what happen... ?

Comment: Attribute error means that the `count` attribute does not exist. 
I don't know what function/attribute gets you the size of the folder, but I suppose you could do `len([i for i in folder.Items])` which gets you the length of the list containing the items in your folder, which should be the same as the number of emails in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the right folderindex:

folder = outlook.Folders[6] for inbox

Other folders:

3  Deleted Items

4  Outbox

5  Sent Items

6  Inbox

9  Calendar

10 Contacts

11 Journal

12 Notes

13 Tasks

14 Drafts

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function helped me see the folder names in Python.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

def see_folders(outlook_object, level=0, trail=''):
    level += 1

    for i in range(outlook_object.Folders.Count):

        if trail == '':
            trail = outlook_object.Folders[i].Name
        elif i == 0:
            trail = trail + '>' + outlook_object.Folders[i].Name # add name to trail
        else:
            trail = trail[:-len('>' + outlook_object.Folders[i-1].Name)] # remove name from previous iteration
            trail = trail + '>' + outlook_object.Folders[i].Name
        #print(trail)
        print('  '*(level-1) + 'Level:' + str(level) + ' Number:' + str(level) + '.' + str(i + 1) + ' Subfolders:' + str(outlook_object.Folders[i].Folders.Count) + ' Path:' + trail)
        if outlook_object.Folders[i].Folders.Count > 0:
            see_folders(outlook_object.Folders[i], level, trail)
        else:
            pass
    return

see_folders(outlook)
```